# python dialogbox in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, dialog

I wrote a simple test program which should continuisly ask the user for a float in a dialogbox without blocking the main program, here in the test I removed it for simplicity.:

```
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog


from queue import Queue # Python 3.x


def ask(x):
    ROOT = tk.Tk()

    ROOT.withdraw()
    # the input dialog
    P = simpledialog.askstring(title="Ref",
                                      prompt="Enter float:")
    if P=="999":
        #end
        return "end"
    else:
        return float(P)

UI=0
threads_running = []
end=0
que = Queue() 
while(end==0):
    if UI==0:
        UI=1
        th = threading.Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(ask(arg1)), args=(que, "x"))
        th.setDaemon(True)
        th.start()
        threads_running.append(th)
        
    for thread in threads_running:
        thread.join(timeout=0)  # non-blocking because timeout=0
        if thread.is_alive():
            # the join has timeout, so the thread is still running
            pass
        else:
            threads_running.remove(thread)
            print(threads_running)
            thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(ask(arg1)), args=(que, "x"))
            thread.setDaemon(True)
            thread.start()
            threads_running.append(thread)
        while not que.empty():
            result = que.get()
            print(result)
            if result=="end":
                end=1
        sleep(1)
```

it works until the the function runs a second time than I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-17:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/kevin/Desktop/PRC/test_dialog.py", line 47, in <lambda>
    thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(ask(arg1)), args=(que, "x"))
  File "C:/Users/kevin/Desktop/PRC/test_dialog.py", line 19, in ask
    P = simpledialog.askstring(title="Ref",
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\simpledialog.py", line 399, in askstring
    d = _QueryString(title, prompt, **kw)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\simpledialog.py", line 376, in __init__
    _QueryDialog.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\simpledialog.py", line 271, in __init__
    Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\simpledialog.py", line 131, in __init__
    Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2616, in __init__
    BaseWidget.__init__(self, master, 'toplevel', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

So the problem seems to be TKinter but I got no clue why it works the first time but not when the second dialogbox is called.
has anyone an idea how to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? In line 37-48, I removed, so there will no more error: `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`

```
while(end==0):
    if UI==0:
        UI=1
        th = threading.Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(ask(arg1)), args=(que, "x"))
        th.setDaemon(True)
        th.start()
        threads_running.append(th)
        
    while not que.empty():
        result = que.get()
        print(result)
        if result=="end":
            end=1
    sleep(1)
```